# Replace Tokens for config.json file not working in Release pipeline

Tags: tfs

I'm using Replace tokens for the config.json from the source control TFS and replace tokens task in Release pipeline.

```
Config.json
```

{
"ConnectionStrings":  "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

}

```
 Config.json
```

{
"ConnectionStrings":  "#{constr}#"

}

using Variable:
Name       Value
Constr     Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User
Id=myUsername;password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;

Replace Token

I'm using config.json

It is not working, Please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Replace Tokens for config.json file not working in Release pipeline

To use this task, make sure following points:

1. Set the correct task configuration, like the `Root directory` and `Target files`:

   [image]
2. Set the correct variable with correct scope:

   [image]
3. Make sure the `config.json` in the Artifacts, you could test it with private agent to check if the `config.json` exists in the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.

As the test result (I checked it with my private agent):

[image]

**Note:** To check the result, we need to check the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in the release pipeline not check the `config.json` in the repo.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I'm using the config.json { }, I don't have the "Data" kind of a config.json, In the release pipeline I'm using Process Variables to pass a Variable for "constr" to the Stage instead of "Release", I've few Variable groups to the Release Pipeline does that make a difference, Please let me know.

Comment: I've multiple config.json files in the drop location under that path, can I give the full name of the config.json in the Target Files?

Comment: @info2m, I could not understand this words " I'm using the config.json { }, I don't have the "Data" kind of a config.json" Could you please explain it more details or you could share this info with a image. Anyway, you need make sure the variable is available before you use the replace token, you could add a command line task to show it.

Comment: @info2m, you could give the full name of the config.json in the Target Files.

Comment: This is my Config.json                                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                              "ConnectionStrings": "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
}

Comment: @info2m, I know that, but do you mean your Config.json is not a file? Can you give me some image in your question, it's hard to understand your question.

Comment: Config.json
{ "ConnectionStrings": "__constr__"
}

Comment: This is has resolved my issue. Thanks Leo "__constr__ " in the json file resolved my issue, double underscore before and after "constr"